# decryption following hash for same Id is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two seperate stored procedures which one is for adding a new employee to DB and the other is for getting an employee from the DB.
I'm using `SHA2_256` and it looks like it works good when inserting the data, but when using the same technique for getting the employee, something is not working.

This is the SP for adding the employee.

```
USE [db11]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[io_sp_admin_add_emp]
@Id BIGINT, @Lname VARCHAR(20), @Fname VARCHAR(15),@Gender TINYINT,@Bday DATETIME,@LoggedInUser VARCHAR(10)

AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @HashId varbinary(50) =  HashBytes('SHA2_256', cast(@Id as varbinary(50)))

INSERT INTO io_t_employees(
 lname,
 fname,
 gender,
 bday,
 [user_name],
 hash_id
 )
 VALUES(

 LTRIM(RTRIM(@Lname)),
 LTRIM(RTRIM(@Fname)),
 @Gender,
 @Bday,
 @loggedInUser,
 @HashId,
 )

SELECT CAST(1 as BIT) as 'Status', 'Succeeded' as 'ReturnMessage' 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH        
END
```

And Then, I would like to get the User's `UniqueId` according to the `HashId` stored earlier.

```
USE [db11]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[io_sp_admin_emp_helper]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id INT

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT UniqueId 
    FROM io_t_employees
    WHERE hash_id = HashBytes('SHA2_256', cast(@id as varbinary(50)))
END
```

Unfortunately ,the result of the second procedure's query has no data. 
I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong in the first procedure (add employee).

Comment: Ones a `bigint`, the others an `int`. There's no guarantee that "equal" values of two different types will produce the same hash. And you're hashing, not encrypting/decrypting.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever would you like me to close it or you want to add your post as an answer?

Comment: I think close. It's pretty close to just being a typo.

Comment: it's just close to be a typo .